# Stata issue with cumulative sum of shares: max value 1 not recognized as such

Tags: stata, cumulative-sum

I will say in advance that I cannot report the data here for confidentiality, and that I modified the figures of reported revenues, but perhaps someone can help me spot any error with the following code, or tell me what's going on with Stata.

I am using the `sum()` function with the `generate` command to obtain the cumulative sum of the yearly revenues of the companies belonging to a specific group as a share of the total yearly revenues from the group.

```
* 1) Derive the shares
sort Group year rev_Tot
by   Group year:         egen rev_Tot_group = total(rev_Tot)

replace rev_Tot_group = rev_Tot / rev_Tot_group 

* 2) Compute the cumulative sum of the shares by group per year

by   Group year: gen Roll_sum_rev_Tot_group = sum(rev_Tot_group)
drop rev_Tot_group
```

So far, so good, apparently. Then I start categorizing the observations by quintiles within group/year - I care doing so only for two groups out of 3.

```
gen quintile = ""
replace quintile = "Group1 0.2" if Roll_sum_rev_Tot_group <= 0.2                                 & Group == "1"
replace quintile = "Group2 0.2" if Roll_sum_rev_Tot_group <= 0.2                                 & Group == "2"
replace quintile = "Group1 0.4" if Roll_sum_rev_Tot_group >  0.2 & Roll_sum_rev_Tot_group <= 0.4 & Group == "1"
replace quintile = "Group2 0.4" if Roll_sum_rev_Tot_group >  0.2 & Roll_sum_rev_Tot_group <= 0.4 & Group == "2"
replace quintile = "Group1 0.6" if Roll_sum_rev_Tot_group >  0.4 & Roll_sum_rev_Tot_group <= 0.6 & Group == "1"
replace quintile = "Group2 0.6" if Roll_sum_rev_Tot_group >  0.4 & Roll_sum_rev_Tot_group <= 0.6 & Group == "2"
replace quintile = "Group1 0.8" if Roll_sum_rev_Tot_group >  0.6 & Roll_sum_rev_Tot_group <= 0.8 & Group == "1"
replace quintile = "Group2 0.8" if Roll_sum_rev_Tot_group >  0.6 & Roll_sum_rev_Tot_group <= 0.8 & Group == "2"
replace quintile = "Group1 1"   if Roll_sum_rev_Tot_group >  0.8 & Roll_sum_rev_Tot_group <= 1   & Group == "1"
replace quintile = "Group2 1"   if Roll_sum_rev_Tot_group >  0.8 & Roll_sum_rev_Tot_group <= 1   & Group == "2"
replace quintile = "Whatever" if Group == "3"
```

At this point, I believe there should be no empty value for `quintile`. However, I discover that one observation is still empty:

```
count if quintile == ""
```

reports `1`.

I therefore browse to see data around that observation

```
br if quintile == ""
br
```

What I see is that were the cumulative sum is 1, `quantile` is empty:

```
Group   year    rev_Tot Roll_sum_rev_Tot_group    quintile
2       2018      37200                .993623    Group2 1
2       2018      37300                .995001    Group2 1
2       2018      43800                .996619    Group2 1
2       2018      45000                .998288    Group2 1
2       2018      46000                      1  
2       2019          0                      0  Group2 0.2
2       2019          0                      0  Group2 0.2
2       2019          0                      0  Group2 0.2
```

I think the problem is in the way Stata reads the "1" from the cumulative sum variable, given that

```
assert(Roll_sum_rev_Tot_group    == 1)  if quintile == ""
```

yields

```
assertion is false
r(9);
```

while

```
assert(Roll_sum_rev_Tot_group    != 1)  if quintile == ""
```

does not produce any error.

However, if I click on the cell in read mode, I see that it is a neat 1. If I check by tabulating, I get 1 again:

```
tab Roll_sum_rev_Tot_group    if quintile == "",m
```

produces

```
Roll_sum_re |
v_Tot_group |  Freq.   Percent     Cum.
------------+---------------------------
          1 |     1     100.00   100.00
------------+---------------------------
      Total |     1     100.00
```

This is quite puzzling to me. Can someone help me understanding what's happening? This is a minor issue to me of course as I could proceed with the analysis, but it is somewhat worrying that I needed to correct for this manually.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is precision. You know that logically the last value should be 1 but Stata does not know that.

The problems start with

```
sort Group year rev_Tot
by   Group year:         egen rev_Tot_group = total(rev_Tot)

replace rev_Tot_group = rev_Tot / rev_Tot_group
```

which I would rewrite as

```
bysort Group year (rev_Tot) : gen double rev_Tot_group = sum(rev_Tot) 
by Group year : replace rev_Tot_group = rev_Tot_group / rev_Tot_group[_N]
```

as there is, or should be, a guarantee that the last value in each block of observations is produced as exactly 1.

Otherwise put, if minute differences are biting you, using `double` as a storage type is the first thing to try.

A secondary issue is display format. You will need to change the display format to get a better idea of what Stata is holding. In extremis, the format `%21x` can be illuminating.

Your quintile assignment code seems rather laboured and for an `input` varying between 0 and 1 might start rather with something with the flavour of

```
gen wanted = ceil(5 * input)
```

See also, if desired, [this paper](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/10.1177/1536867X1801800311).